# Add extra columns to an already existing column

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is there a way to add an extra columns to an already existing table? for example, adding extra columns `user` which is `null` for all the rows and column `date` set to `2015-02-01`

```
serial:long, title:chararray, year:int,score:float
(49586,Winter Wonderland,2013,2.8)
(49587,Top Gear: Series 19: Africa Special,2013,3.1)
(49588,Fireplace For Your Home: Crackling Fireplace with Music,2010,7.3)

grunt>
serial:long, title:chararray, year:int,score:float,user:long,date:chararray
(49586,Winter Wonderland,2013,2.8, ,2015-02-01 )
(49587,Top Gear: Series 19: Africa Special,2013,3.1, ,015-02-01 )
(49588,Fireplace For Your Home: Crackling Fireplace with Music,2010,7.3, ,015-02-01 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input**

```
49586,Winter Wonderland,2013,2.8
49587,Top Gear: Series 19: Africa Special,2013,3.1
49588,Fireplace For Your Home: Crackling Fireplace with Music,2010,7.3
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') AS (serial:long,title:chararray,year:int,score:float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE serial,title,year,score, null AS (user:long) ,'2015-02-01' AS (date:chararray);
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(49586,Winter Wonderland,2013,2.8,,2015-02-01)
(49587,Top Gear: Series 19: Africa Special,2013,3.1,,2015-02-01)
(49588,Fireplace For Your Home: Crackling Fireplace with Music,2010,7.3,,2015-02-01)
```